# how to pass variable content to function in powershell

Tags: function, powershell

I found this awesome [function](https://foxdeploy.com/code-and-scripts/search-google/) by STEPHEN OWEN.
I want to use it to check several URLs on a CSV or text file.
so if I use

```
$URLs = import-content c:\myurllist.txt
```

how do I pass the content of the variable `$URLs` one by one into the function?

thanks

Comment: `$URLs |%{Search-Google $_}`

Comment: thanks, this worked.

Comment: is it possible to display the result in the powershell console so that if the search produces a result, I will get an OK/no result message instead of opening the browser for every query?

Comment: No, you will have to use Invoke-WebRequest for that